# Can't install (Failed to fetch http://packages.ros.org/ros/ubuntu/dists/precise/Release )

Tags: ros

[image: Rosanswers logo]

I've followed the install tutorial several times but I keep getting the following error:

W: Failed to fetch http://packages.ros.org/ros/ubuntu/dists/precise/Release  Unable to find expected entry '/etc/apt/sources.list.d/ros-latest.list/binary-amd64/Packages' in Release file (Wrong sources.list entry or malformed file)

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/40048/can%27t-install-(failed-to-fetch-http://packages.ros.org/ros/ubuntu/dists/precise/release-)/) by [jd](https://answers.ros.org/users/2939/jd/) on ROS Answers with karma: 62 on 2012-07-27

Post score: 0

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [allenh1](https://answers.ros.org/users/1086/allenh1/) on 2012-07-27**:
Have you tried deleting that file? Checked your Internet connection? Are you certain that you got the keys?

**Comment by [jd](https://answers.ros.org/users/2939/jd/) on 2012-07-28**:
I deleted that file and started over again.  It seems to be working now.  Thanks!

**Comment by [allenh1](https://answers.ros.org/users/1086/allenh1/) on 2012-07-28**:
No problem! Glad I could help!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

From the comments, the solution to this problem is to run the following:

```
sudo rm -f /etc/apt/sources.list.d/ros-latest.list/binary-amd64/Packages
```

Then just start the install tutorial over again.

---

Originally posted by [allenh1](https://answers.ros.org/users/1086/allenh1/) with karma: 3055 on 2012-07-28

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 1